# Writing code for Flattening of a Linked List but unable to accomplish the task

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

You are given a linked list containing ***'n'*** ***'head'*** nodes, where every node in the linked list contains two pointers:

(1) ***‘next’*** which points to the next node in the list

(2) ***‘child’*** pointer to a linked list where the current node is the head.

Each of these child linked lists is in sorted order and connected by 'child' pointer.

Your task is to flatten this linked such that all nodes appear in a single layer or level in a ***'sorted order'**.*

This is the question I am trying to solve however I am only able flatten the first child list after that my program exits for some reason.[image]

This is my current code:-

```
public class Solution {
    public static Node flattenLinkedList(Node head) {
        //Write your code here
        if(head == null||head.next==null){
            return head;
        }
        Node childptr = head.child;
        Node listptr = head;
        Node temp = listptr.next;
        while(temp!=null){
            // Node next = childptr.child;
            childptr.next = listptr.next;
            listptr.next = childptr;
            listptr = listptr.next;
            
            childptr = childptr.child;
            if(childptr==null){
                childptr = temp.child;
                listptr = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the output I am getting.

Comment: Don't tag with `dsa` (read the tag description)

Comment: You're quite far from a correct solution. Use the example and design the algorithm first. You have a collection of sorted lists and must produce a single completely sorted result. This means you'll need to merge all input lists: repeatedly pop the smallest head node from its list and append it to the result. How can you accomplish that?

Comment: I agree with Gene. You perform node mutations without checking whether the connected nodes are in the expected order.  Your code never looks at the *value* of a node, which is of course necessary to guarantee that you're constructing a list that is sorted. You return `head`, but `head` is not necessarily the node with the least value (only child-lists are known to be sorted, the next-list is not necessary sorted). Back to the drawing board.

Comment: BTW, what is *"a single layer or level"*. Is that a list connected by `next` or by `child`?